# How display MessageBox without show application icon in Windows taskbar?

Tags: delphi, messagebox, delphi-10-seattle

I have a dll that is injected in a process and this dll contains a Form where i want use `MessageBox()` (or some other type of dialog) to alert the user about some operations.

Eg:

```
Application.MessageBox('successful operation!','Information',mb_Ok+mb_IconInformation);
```

Happens that everytime that this is showed, also is showed the icon of target application in Windows taskbar, and i not want this.

Then i want display these messages without show application icon in taskbar.
How make this?

Comment: Call MessageBox instead

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, thank you. Worked.

Comment: To clarify David's comment, call the Win32 API `MessageBox()` function instead of the VCL's `Application.MessageBox()` method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Delphi 7, `Application.MessageBox()` calls the Win32 API [`MessageBox()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox) function specifying the `Application.Handle` as the owner window <sup>1</sup>.

Inside a DLL, `Application.Handle` is 0 by default, so your `MessageBox` dialog is being displayed without an owner window assigned to it.  That explains why it is able to appear on the Taskbar, as only a top-level unowned window (with the `APP_EX_APPWINDOW` extended style) can appear there.

So, the simplest solution is to call the Win32 API `MessageBox()` function yourself, specifying an owner `HWND` that belongs to the app you have injected your DLL into.  Or, if you want to keep using `Application.MessageBox()`, assign such an `HWND` to the `Application.Handle` property after the DLL has been injected.

But either way, make sure the thread that is calling `MessageBox()` is attached to the message queue of the chosen owner `HWND`.  If you are calling `MessageBox()` in a separate thread, use [`AttachThreadInput()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-attachthreadinput) to make that attachment before calling `MessageBox()`, and again to remove the attachment after `MessageBox()` exits.

<sup>1: In later Delphi versions, `Application.MessageBox` uses the [`Application.OnGetActiveFormHandle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.OnGetActiveFormHandle) event, the Win32 [`GetActiveWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getactivewindow) function, and the Win32 [`GetLastActivePopup()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getlastactivepopup) function (in that order) to find a suitable owner window before resorting to using the `Application.Handle`.</sup>

Comment: If I could upvote twice, I would. I never knew about `AttachThreadInput()`.